# Backing up exchange 2003

Tags: backup, exchange, hard-drive

I am trying to backup Exchange 2003 with the Windows Backup tool but due to bad block on the hard drive, I am getting the following error.

```
Backup Status
Operation: Backup
Active backup destination: File
Media name: "BackupExchange.bkf created 05/10/2010 at 09:08"

Volume shadow copy creation: Attempt 1.
Backup of "SERVER01\Microsoft Information Store\First Storage Group"
Backup set #1 on media #1
Backup description: "Set created 05/10/2010 at 09:08"
Media name: "BackupExchange.bkf created 05/10/2010 at 09:08"

Backup Type: Normal

Backup started on 05/10/2010 at 09:08.
The 'Microsoft Information Store' returned 'A disk I/O error occurred.

' from a call to 'HrESEBackupRead()' additional data '-'The 'Microsoft Information Store' returned 'A disk I/O error occurred.

' from a call to 'HrESEBackupRead()' additional data '-'
The operation was ended.
Backup completed on 05/10/2010 at 13:35.
Directories: 0
Files: 2
Bytes: 60,078,699,258
Time:  4 hours,  26 minutes, and  51 seconds

----------------------

The operation did not successfully complete.

----------------------
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how to backup Exchange so I can swap the duff disk or am I doomed to lose emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is the most important part; and the easiest to backup (relatively speaking). You can simply stop the Exchange Store service, or dismount the store(s) in Exchange's System Manager. Then copy the MBDDATA folder. It should have the main database (commonly priv1.edb),  all the log files (ie E123456.log), and the stream file (priv1.stm). If you have public folders they'll have a similar naming scheeme; in any case just copy the whole folder if you can.

The database can be remounted on a freshly installed server, and reconnected to existing users, with relative easy, and there are articles around on Exchange disaster recovery. Be sure to find those instructions and follow them carefully.

Try copying the folder with something like `xcopy /c /e /j MDBDATA X:\TmpFolder` where the current directory is the exchange installation directory and the X: drive is a network folder, or removable HD, or something safe.